# How can I compile the Devanagari preprocessor in Linux?

Tags: fonts, linux, indic

At the moment I am writing a paper that requires some Devanagari letters. I am using the Velthuis [Devanagari](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/language/devanagari/velthuis) package. The problem is that some letters show up correctly after LaTeX-ing, but others do not. I think this has to do with the preprocessor, which the documentation says must be compiled in order to function. However, as someone who is not a programmer and relatively new to Linux. Can anyone tell me how to do this simply? I have been messing with this for about 6 hours now and I haven't gotten anywhere.

Comment: Because this is about compiling a software under Linux, not about (La)TeX directly, it might be better placed on our sister site http://unix.stackexchange.com or http://superuser.com. I can migrate it there. You would need to rephrase it a little for this.

Answer (score 5):

It is easy on Linux :)

1. Download the file  http://mirrors.ctan.org/language/devanagari/velthuis/bin/devnag.c
2. Say from the command line `gcc -o devnag devnag.c`
3. Optionally install the file into `/usr/local/bin`: `sudo install devnag /usr/local/bin`

Comment: Right I've got that but my main problem is that when I run the gcc command I get:                                <install: cannot stat `devnag': No such file or directory>  Do I have to save the file somewhere special?

Comment: Are you sure you get this when you run `gcc`?  Maybe when you run `install`?

Comment: Well I think I downloaded it using sudo apt-get and I have an executable program in  /usr/bin named devnag, but when I run the file.dn command in terminal it says "cannot open the file"