# Uploading XeLaTex compiled source to ArXiv

Tags: xetex, luatex, arxiv

I am trying add a Tex source files which should be compiled using XeLaTex in OverLeaf, since some external dependencies were used to add fonts from other languages except English. ArXiv does not accept source files complaining,

```
!Fatal Package fontspec Error: The fontspec package requires either XeTeX or(fontspec) LuaTeX.
(fontspec)
(fontspec) You must change your typesetting engine to,
(fontspec) e.g., "xelatex" or "lualatex"instead of
(fontspec) "latex" or "pdflatex".
```

Is there any procedure to mitigate this issue ?

Comment: Unfortunately, arXiv won’t compile submissions compiled with a modern toolchain. It even specifically tries to check whether a PDF you submit was made in XeTeX or LuaTeX, and reject it. I wish they and other publishers who still require PDFTeX would change their policy. Everyone but the dinosaurs who already know LaTeX like the backs of their hands could upgrade.

Comment: Then, I wouldn’t have to spend twice as long on every answer, just to say, “Or if you have to use PDFTeX, ....”

Comment: You might also be able to use [this workaround](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/544153/devanagari-typesetting-in-windows-texmaker-miktex).

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If your problem is compiling in Overleaf, you need to change the compiler to XeLaTeX on Menu.

In any case, you can try adding a magic comment to tell AutoTeX which engine to use. Add this to the top of your main `.tex` file:

```
% !TeX TS-program = xelatex
```

Comment: Will this work for Arxiv auto generation process

Comment: I believe the question is about submitting to arXiv, not compiling in Overleaf.